# How to know the index value selected / opened tab Flex (TabNavigator)

Tags: actionscript-3, mxml, flex4.5

I have a mx Tab navigator and added several childs...I can use selectedindex(int) to open/select the respective (int) tab but How do I know the value of a selected/open tab???

Any Ideas.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `selectedIndex` property (it is readable/writable). Also see `Event.CHANGED` to catch tab change.

Comment: To select/open/focus on no. 2 tab we use tabs.selectedIndex=2; where tabs is the id of tab navigator. Can we do this too var asd:int = tabs.selectIndex;

Comment: Ya done..Thanks I overlooked that selectedIndex was readable/writable

Answer (score 1):

You mean the navigator content?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
               minWidth="955"
               minHeight="600">


    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.core.INavigatorContent;
            import mx.events.IndexChangedEvent;

            protected function tabNavigator_changeHandler(event:IndexChangedEvent):void
            {
                var obj:INavigatorContent = tabNavigator.selectedChild;
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <mx:TabNavigator id="tabNavigator"
                     change="tabNavigator_changeHandler(event)" />

</s:Application>
```

Comment: NO, If we do this <mx: TabNavigator id =tabs"> tabs.selectedIndex = 2; we focus/open/select the tab no. 2....

Comment: Now if there are 6 tabs and user switches a to a tab how to determine which tabindex is now selected/opened/focused

Comment: oh, you said: "I can use selectedindex(int)" - so you'd already solved your own problem upon post.